# How to get the list of the center of coordinates of bounding boxes python

Tags: python

I what to get the list of the centers of the bounding boxes of my object detection model and I wrote the code below but it is not working. Would appriciate if anyone could help me out with it. And also I would like to get the distances between the center points of the bounding boxes as well.

```
def find_centerpoint_box(detections):
    coord = []
    for detection in detections:
        box = detection['box']
        x = int(([box][0] + [box][2]) / 2) - offset
        y = int(([box][1] + [box][3]) / 2) - offset
        coord = np.array(x,y)
        print (coord)
   
   return find_midpoint_box
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: Hi @mkrieger1The coordinates are not getting displayed when I run the code.

Comment: Maybe you didn't call the function?